# Scrapy Crawled (302) Status, how to handle

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

```
import scrapy


class Pttscrapper2Spider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'PTTscrapper2'
    allowed_domains = ['https://www.ptt.cc']
    start_urls = ['https://www.ptt.cc/bbs/HatePolitics/index.html/']
    handle_httpstatus_list = [400, 302]

    def parse(self, response):
        urls = response.css('div.r-ent > div.title > a::attr(href)').extract()
        for thread_url in urls:
            url = response.urljoin(thread_url)
            yield scrapy.Request(url=url, callback=self.parse_details)

        next_page_url = response.css('a.wide:nth-child(2)::attr(href)').extract_first()
        if next_page_url:
            next_page_url = response.urljoin(next_page_url)
            yield scrapy.Request(url=next_page_url, callback=self.parse)            


    def parse_details(self, response):
        yield {
                'title' : response.xpath('//head/title/text()').extract(),
                'stance' : response.xpath('//*[@id="main-content"]/div[@class="push"]/span[1]/text()').extract(),
                'userid' : response.xpath('//*[@id="main-content"]/div[@class="push"]/span[2]/text()').extract(),
                'comment' : response.xpath('//*[@id="main-content"]/div[@class="push"]/span[3]/text()').extract(),
                'time_of_post' : response.xpath('//*[@id="main-content"]/div[@class="push"]/span[4]/text()').extract(),
        }
```

I've been using the above spider to try and crawl a website, but I when I run the spider, I get these messages:

```
> 2017-10-05 23:14:27 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Spider opened
> 2017-10-05 23:14:27 [scrapy.extensions.logstats] INFO: Crawled 0 pages
> (at 0 pages/min), scraped 0 items (at 0 items/min) 2017-10-05 23:14:27
> [scrapy.extensions.telnet] DEBUG: Telnet console listening on
> 127.0.0.1:6023 2017-10-05 23:14:28 [scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.cookies] DEBUG: Received cookies from:
> <302 https://www.ptt.cc/bbs/HatePolitics/index.html/> Set-Cookie:
> __cfduid=d3ca57dcab04acfaf256438a57c547e4a1507216462; expires=Fri, 05-Oct-18 15:14:22 GMT; path=/; domain=.ptt.cc; HttpOnly
> 
> 2017-10-05 23:14:28 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (302) <GET
> https://www.ptt.cc/bbs/HatePolitics/index.html/> (referer: None)
> 2017-10-05 23:14:28 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Closing spider
> (finished)
```

What I've been thinking is that my spider can't seem to access the sub forums in the index. I've tested that the selectors point to the correct locations and request.urljoin creates the correct absolute url but can't seem to access the sub forums in a page. It would be great if someone can tell me why the spider is unable to access the links!

Comment: Why have you put `handle_httpstatus_list`? You are not handling those error codes and you should remove it

Comment: I've removed the handle_httpstatus, but now the error is, me being directed to the wrong url? 

`code` 2017-10-06 00:46:33 [scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.redirect] DEBUG: Redirecting (302) to <GET https://www.ptt.cc/bbs/HatePolitics/index.html/index.html> from <GET https://www.ptt.cc/bbs/HatePolitics/index.html/>
2017-10-06 00:46:36 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (404) <GET https://www.ptt.cc/bbs/HatePolitics/index.html/index.html> (referer: None)
`code`

Answer (score 0):

Two issues with your scraper. In the `start_urls` you added a trailing slash to the `index.html/`, which is wrong. Next `allowed_domains` will take domain names and not urls.

Change starting code to below and it would work

```
class Pttscrapper2Spider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'PTTscrapper2'
    allowed_domains = ['www.ptt.cc']
    start_urls = ['https://www.ptt.cc/bbs/HatePolitics/index.html']
```

Logs from the run

```
2017-10-06 13:16:15 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://www.ptt.cc/bbs/HatePolitics/M.1507268600.A.57C.html> (referer: https://www.ptt.cc/bbs/HatePolitics/index.html)
2017-10-06 13:16:15 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://www.ptt.cc/bbs/HatePolitics/M.1507268600.A.57C.html>
{'title': ['[黑特] 先刪文，洪慈庸和高潞那個到底撤案了沒？ - 看板 HatePolitics - 批踢踢實業坊'], 'stance': ['推 ', '→ ', '噓 ', '→ ', '→ '], 'userid': ['ABA0525', 'gerund', 'AGODFATHER', 'laman45', 'victoryman'], 'comment': [': 垃圾不分藍綠黃', ': 垃圾靠弟傭 中華民國內最沒資格當立委的爛貨', ': 說什麼東西你個板啊', ': 有確定再說', ': 看起來應該是撤了'], 'time_of_post': ['10/06 13:43\n', '10/06 13:50\n', '10/06 13:57\n', '10/06 13:59\n', ' 10/06 15:27\n']}
2017-10-06 13:16:15 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://www.ptt.cc/bbs/HatePolitics/M.1507275599.A.657.html> (referer: https://www.ptt.cc/bbs/HatePolitics/index.html)
```